# DataScraping using Jsoup in java

Tags: java, jsoup, data-science

I'm developing a java program to scrape data from a specific site. I'm using jSoup as java module.

http://data.bitcoinity.org/markets/tradespm/10m?c=e&t=a
that is the website

and i am trying to scrap the example data below on that website.

bitflyer    144    14.17%

coinbase    121     11.89%

I have tried in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
            "http://data.bitcoinity.org/markets/tradespm/10m?c=e&t=a")
            .get();

    for (Element table : doc.select("tbody")){
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");


            System.out.println(row);
            System.out.println(tds);

        }
    }


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

any help? scraping the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the data in the round another way. The `Jsoup` is very good for parsing static content, but for dynamic content, you need to find another way. If you keenly observe the API calls made, then the table is loaded from the GET request on http://data.bitcoinity.org/chart_data

You can parse the JSON content in to get the data. I use OkHttp3 for retrieving the data.

```
// Imports required
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://data.bitcoinity.org/chart_data")
            .build();
    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
    JSONArray aggregated = responseBody.getJSONObject("data_additional")
            .getJSONArray("aggregated");
    for (int i = 0; i < aggregated.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject rowInfo = aggregated.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(rowInfo.getString("key") + ", " + rowInfo.getDouble("agg") + ", " + rowInfo.getString("share"));
    }
}
```

The above code will generate the response like

```
bit-x, 128103.3596, 4.39
bitfinex, 788172.829602228, 27.00
bitflyer, 385999.821606005, 13.22
bitstamp, 345652.20203694, 11.84
coinbase, 320228.256592679, 10.97
gemini, 99966.4119466147, 3.42
hitbtc, 222472.499999999, 7.62
itbit, 161030.4573, 5.52
kraken, 287811.61880974, 9.86
others, 179860.514253696, 6.16
```